# MySQL - group_concat pulling in additional incorrect data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-concat

I'm having trouble with a `JOIN` and a `GROUP_CONCAT`. The query is concatenating additional data that should not be associated with the join.

Here's my table structure:

```
linkages
ID       table_name     tag_id
1        subcategories  6
2        categories     9

music
ID       artwork
1        5
2        4

artwork
ID       url_path
1        /some/file/path
2        /some/file/path
```

And here's my query:

```
SELECT music.*,
       artwork.url_path AS artwork_url_path,
       GROUP_CONCAT( linkages.tag_id ) AS tag_ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT( linkages.table_name ) AS table_name 
FROM music
LEFT JOIN artwork ON artwork.id = music.artwork 
LEFT JOIN linkages ON music.id = linkages.track_id 
WHERE music.id IN( '1356',
                   '1357',
                   '719',
                   '169',
                   '170',
                   '171',
                   '805' )
ORDER BY FIELD( music.id,
                1356,
                1357,
                719,
                169,
                170,
                171,
                805 )
```

This is the result of the `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
[tag_ids] => 3, 6, 9, 17, 19, 20, 26, 49, 63, 64, 53, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 79, 80, 85, 96, 98, 11, 53, 67, 3, 6, 15, 17, 26, 38, 50, 63, 74, 53, 56, 57, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 72, 85, 88, 98, 24, 69, 71, 3, 6, 15, 17, 26, 38, 50
```

The first portion of the result is correct:

```
[tag_ids] => 3, 6, 9, 17, 19, 20, 26, 49, 63, 64, 53, 57, 63, 65, 67, 73, 79, 80, 85, 96, 98, 11, 53, 67
```

Everything after the correct values seems random and most of the values don't exist in the result in the database, but it's still pulling it in.  It seems to repeat a portion of the correct result (`3, 6, 15, 17` - the `3, 6, 17` are correct, but `15` shouldn't be there, similar with a bunch of other numbers - `71`, etc.  I can't use `DISTINCT` because I need to match up the `tag_id`s and `table_name` results as a multidimensional array from the results.

Any thoughts as to why?

**UPDATE**:
I ended up solving it with the initial push from Gordon. It needed a GROUP_BY clause, otherwise it was putting every results tag id's in each result. The final query ended up becoming this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT 
music.*, 
artwork.url_path as artwork_url_path,
GROUP_CONCAT(linkages.tag_id, ':', linkages.table_name) as tags 
FROM music 
LEFT JOIN artwork ON artwork.id = music.artwork 
LEFT JOIN linkages ON music.id = linkages.track_id 
WHERE music.id IN('1356', '1357', '719', '169', '170', '171', '805') 
GROUP BY music.id
ORDER BY FIELD(music.id,1356,1357,719,169,170,171,805);
```

Comment: Please share your table schema. In your data, there are multiple *linkages.track_id* per one *music.id*, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I just posted the structure of the 2 tables that I'm working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `join` is generating duplicate rows.  I would suggest that you fix the root cause of the problem.  But, a quick-and-dirty solution is to use `group_concat(distinct)`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT linkages.tag_id) as tag_ids, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT linkages.table_name) as table_name
```

You can put the columns in a single field using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT linkages.tag_id, ':', linkages.table_name) as tags
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't use a distinct because I need to match up the tag_ids and table_name results as a multidimensional array. Any idea on how to fix the join?

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I ended up solving it and posted an update in my original question.